# Keeping Data synchronously From Posts with same UploadKey

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app where you can post pictures in different categories.
For instance : Animals / Motorcycles.

My user can follow users and see therefor their pictures.

Now I am working on the following: I want to upload a post in a category and at the same time in all posts( a separate screen where users can randomly see all posted pictures)

Every Posts, no matter where posted, will be in the allPosts child

```
var REF_POST = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
```

and for each category there is a specific child where just the posts from this category stay in

```
var REF_POST = Database.database().reference().child("motorcycles")
```

Now in the feed you can like and comment without a problem.
It uses the data from the child "allPosts"

Now I would like to automatically keep the data in synchrony with the post in motorcycles. They both share the same key but obviously it only get updated in the "allPosts" child.

The goal is to update each category always on the data from "allPosts" and reverse. So if a user liked in the category it will be also updated in "allPosts".

Update Code

```
func incrementLikesFeed(postId: String,  onSuccess: @escaping (Post) -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void){
    let postRef = API.Post.REF_POSTS.child(postId)

    postRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
        if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = API.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid {

            var likes: Dictionary<String, Bool>
            likes = post["likes"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
            var likeCount = post["likeCount"] as? Int ?? 0
            var score = post["score"] as? Int ?? 0

            if let _ = likes[uid] {
                likeCount -= 1
                score -= 100
                likes.removeValue(forKey: uid)
                self.REF_LIKES_POSTS.child(postId).child(uid).removeValue()

            } else {

                likeCount += 1
                score += 100
                likes[uid] = true
                self.REF_LIKES_POSTS.child(postId).child(uid).setValue(true)
            }

            post["score"] = score as AnyObject?
            post["likeCount"] = likeCount as AnyObject?
            post["likes"] = likes as AnyObject?
            currentData.value = post

            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            onError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let dict = snapshot?.value as? [String: Any] {
            let post = Post.transformPost(dict: dict, key: snapshot!.key)
        onSuccess(post)
        }
    }

}
```

this for example updates the like node in all posts.
As I will have 10+ categories, I would love to update always the fitting post in the specific database path

example:

```
database.database().reference.child("Text").child("shortJokes")
database.database().reference.child("allPosts") -> where all posts are
```

how can I achieve that only the specific child gets updated?

because later I will have it like that

```
database.database().reference.child("Text").child("Sport")
database.database().reference.child("Text").child("Animals")
database.database().reference.child("Pictures").child("funnyPictures")
database.database().reference.child("Pictures").child("sweetAnimals")
```

I want it to check through the entire database off all posts to look where a child contains the same postId.
I see the problem when I have 10+ categories I have to call 10 functions in one and probably it will always update everything instead of just the one post with same id.

Update

```
            let newUserData = ["score": score, "likeCount": likeCount, "likes": likes] as [String : Any]

            let postRefEinzeiler = self.REF_EINZEILER.child(postId)
            postRefEinzeiler.updateChildValues(newUserData)

            let postRefSchwHumor = self.REF_SCHWARZERHUMOR.child(postId)
            postRefSchwHumor.updateChildValues(newUserData)
```

With this code snippet I managed to achieve what I wanted to do.
BUT, it always adds a node with the postId in the other categories with the data I provide.

How I can make it to first look if the postId already exists and only if it exists to update the value?

Comment: This is known as client-side fan out and is covered in this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html. Each second snippet is Swift code.

Comment: The problem is that I will have around 20 categories

Comment: Fanning out to 20 categories is a fairly simple  operation, one that you could easily do client-side. What problem do you see with the approach (and code) from the blog post?

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand how I can apply it to my situation

Comment: Ok I managed to do so but I guess not that elegantly. Can you please look over my updated question? Thank you!

Comment: Jen's answer shows how to update two paths at the same time. Doing 20 of them is just more of the same. But you're calling `updateChildValues()` twice, which means that you're sending two command to the database, instead of a single (bigger) command. Checking if the post already exists would require a read operation. Since you're updating, that would most likely imply that you need a transaction. Unfortunately you cannot combine a transaction with a multi-location update.

Comment: Just for my reference, can you please post the firebase node structure..

Comment: Is that a problem that I always create the child in every category? I mean its a lot of wasted paths, but does it matter? Does it slow down the process or possibly crash my app?

Answer (score 1):

```
var BASE_POST = Database.database().reference()

// Generate a new push ID for the new post
let postkey = ENTER YOUR POST_ID 
let postData = YOUR_POST_DETAILS_DICTIONARY

// Create the data we want to update
let updatedPostData = ["posts/\(postkey)": postData, 
              "motorcycles/\(postkey)": postData ]


// Do a deep-path update
ref.updateChildValues(updatedPostData, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) -> Void in
    if (error) {
        print("Error updating data: \(error.description)")
    }
})
```

Comment: i will have like 20 categories, isn't there a way to search through the database for the exact same key?